Djoser Create User keeps returning field required and is not creating users
I ran into a problem in postman that was not there until yesterday when I was working with it and it was working fine, but now it is not working anymore.
I'm trying to create a user using djoser default path, but whenever I send request, I face required field for username and password while both exist, I also send email field which is required by django, but no help.
I tried some hints over internet but no luck.
In setting, the code is like this for djoser:

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',  # djoser
    'djoser',  # djoser
    'main',
)

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {  # 002
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',  # 012 Session --> Tokan  #djoser
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS':  # 011
        'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination', 'PAGE_SIZE': 1,
    'DEFAULT_THOTTLE_CLASSES': (  # 014
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRareThrottle',
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRareThrottle',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {  # 014
        'anon': '5/minute',
        'user': '10/minute',
    },

}
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": False,
    "BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION": False,
    "UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN": False,  # djoser
}

DJOSER = {
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'main.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
    },
}

And these are the serializers I wrote to solve the problem:
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        extra_kwargs = {'is_superuser': {'write_only': True},
                        'is_staff': {'write_only': True},
                        'is_active': {'write_only': True},
                        'date_joined': {'write_only': True},
                        'groups': {'write_only': True},
                        'user_permissions': {'write_only': True}}
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"


class UserCreateSerializer(BaseUserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(BaseUserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'email']

When I enter the information in postman, it gives error 400
In fact, I want to create a user with this URL
http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/users/
and this parameter:
{
    "username": "user21",
    "email": "test@any.com",
    "password": "user_2024AA@",
}


What should I do?

trailing commas are not permitted in JSON. the JSON parse may be failing and somewhere internally returning an empty object, leading to these errors?

David Culbreth I removed the last comma, but it didn't change and the error Bad Request: /auth/users/
[02/Aug/2024 16:19:39] "POST /auth/users/ HTTP/1.1" 400 79
gives

What do you mean that you wrote a serializer for Djoser? Are you using a custom view(set)? If so, please show what it looks like. And what do the contents of your urls.py look like?

This is the serializer I wrote for this
class UserCreateSerializer(BaseUserCreateSerializer):
class Meta(BaseUserCreateSerializer.Meta):
fields = ['username', 'password', 'email']
And I have written three videos for RequestViewSet, AdminViewSet and RespondViewSet
And I have also written this:
UserCreate(APIView)
for Get and Post
